# Scala Doobie not inserting values into database

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, doobie

My code to insert values is:

```
def insert(link: entity.Link) : IO[Int] = {
    logger.info("Inserting link: " + link.toString())
    sql"insert into links (title,url,publication_date,feed_id) values (${link.getTitle},${link.getUrl},${link.getPublicationDate},${link.getFeed.getId})"
        .update
        .run
        .transact(transactor)
}
```

The method calling it is:

```
    val links = for{
        feeds <- getFeeds()
        ls: List[Link] = feeds.flatMap(rssFeedReader.readFeedItems(_).asScala)
        
        ios = ls.map(
            link => 
                linkPersistence
                    .countByUrl(link.getUrl())
                    .map(x => if(x==0) linkPersistence.insert(link) else identity(x))
            
        )

        s <- ios.sequence
    }yield(s)
    val result = links.unsafeRunSync()
    logger.info("Result: " + result.toString())
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use For Expressions, because `IO` doesn't have `withFilter` and I am inside a Maven project (I am migrating a Spring Boot application to Typelevel stack), so I cannot use the improved For Expressions sbt plugin.

My problem is that rows are not inserted into the database.
On the log there is:

```
reddit_bot_1  | 2021-04-23 13:06:57.805  INFO 1 --- [text-global-167] r.i.repository.LinkPersistence           : Inserting link: Link{id=0, feed=Feed{id=79, url='https://ytali.com/feed/'}, title='Se il grillo non fosse stato parlante', url='https://ytali.com/2021/04/21/se-il-grillo-non-fosse-stato-parlante/', publicationDate=Wed Apr 21 11:12:59 GMT 2021}
reddit_bot_1  | 2021-04-23 13:06:57.838  INFO 1 --- [text-global-167] r.i.repository.LinkPersistence           : Inserting link: Link{id=0, feed=Feed{id=82, url='https://cronacheletterarie.com/feed/'}, title='Scrivere come in una serie tv', url='https://www.cronacheletterarie.com/2021/04/22/scrivere-come-in-una-serie-tv-due-nuovi-thriller-italiani/', publicationDate=Thu Apr 22 06:50:30 GMT 2021}
reddit_bot_1  | 2021-04-23 13:06:57.993  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] reddit_bot.service.LinkUpdater           : Result: List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$970148716, IO$398844220, IO$2051359159, IO$1102460161, IO$1646104176, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$1525243662, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$183629085, IO$2057291647, IO$1962915922, IO$1686018284, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$1629671523, IO$1703036679, IO$1823891149, IO$2090799695, IO$189359223, IO$2089070694, IO$572184845, IO$638827115, IO$1723402242, IO$1063752499, IO$1262614371, IO$1882901634, IO$1592599455, IO$1561386362, IO$422495060, IO$1071010351, IO$135298961, IO$1395689700, IO$1022084533, IO$824291117, IO$977707631, IO$1835432555, IO$264428575, IO$858145293, IO$1014815708, IO$1654086426, IO$2074886515, IO$2048606753, IO$551801989, IO$2029261832, IO$1640654268, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$1096825326, IO$2132380347, IO$664110340, IO$364966863, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$1429149648, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, IO$1724908444, IO$1835403239, IO$2133511951, IO$1385617069, IO$876405632, IO$1773704159, IO$1078164304, IO$604307019, IO$2004298152, 1, IO$1526495986, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

The transactor is created like this:

```
def transactor() = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
  "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
  "jdbc:mysql://database:3306/redditbot",
  "redditbot",
  "redditbot"
)
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @luis-miguel-mejía-suárez I modified my `pom.xml` file like this:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <compilerPlugin>
                        <groupId>com.olegpy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>better-monadic-for_2.13</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3.1</version>
                    </compilerPlugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But the problem remains.

Comment: [**bm4**](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) is a compiler plugin, not a **sbt** plugin. So you can also add it to a **maven** build. Follow the instructions of [**kind-projector**](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector) and adapt it to **bm4** _(once you get it running it may be good to open a PR to the **bm4** project to add the **maven** instructions to their `README`)_ - But I am not sure if that would indeed or not fix your problem. - BTW, `map` + `sequence` = `traverse`

Comment: Are you sure statements in `insert` are not another way around?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik sorry, I can't understand what you mean. The problem is with the `insert` statements?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez unfortunately, that doesn't work. See this issueI opened: https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for/issues/52

Comment: @VitalyOlegovitch `if foo` will not work with `IO` not even using **bm4**, **bm4** helps removing unnecessary `withFilter` calls to things like `(a, b) <- IO.pure(3 -> 5)` - BTW, you should not need to also add the plugin as a normal dependency.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You are right, you already explained that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715182/value-withfilter-is-not-a-member-of-cats-io-in-for-comprehension/55716191#comment98111109_55715182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

> As the error clearly says, **IO** does not have a `withFilter` method. ([You can check the scaladoc here](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/IO.html)). When you put the type explicitly, you are basically filtering all elements that match such type. And, since the method does not exists, it won't compile. - And no, I do not know any workaround.

> But, I can think on at least ne reason of why it should not have it. **IO** is not exactly a *"container"* of elements, like List, since it only is a description of a computation, and if you ant to see it like a container it will only had one element, like Option. But, unlike the former, there is not concept of *empty **IO***. Thus, filtering an IO would not make sense.

The workaround that I have found is moving the filter inside another function :

```
def insertIfNotPresent(link: Link, foundLinksCount: Int): IO[Option[Int]] = 
    foundLinksCount match{
        case 0 => linkPersistence.insert(link).map(Option(_))
        case _ => IO.pure(None)
    }
```

The calling code becomes:

```
for{
  foundLinksCount: Int <- linkPersistence.countByUrl(link.getUrl())
  n: Option[Int] <- insertIfNotPresent(link, foundLinksCount)
}yield(n)
```